# Is there a way to get values of non selected items in a dropdown?

Tags: jquery, html

Given below is the referred html. Suppose if user just selects any one option and submits the form. I want to know which options were left unchecked/unselected?

Using this : $('#staff_id option:not(:selected)'); gives object of what I am looking for but I need values.

Using this: $('#staff_id option:not(:selected)').val(); gives value just for the first one unselected.

```
<select class="mdb-select initialized" id="staff_id" name="staff_id[]" multiple="" searchable="Search here...">
<option value="0" disabled="" selected="">Select</option>
<option value="712">Alex</option>
<option value="468">Verk</option>
<option value="470">Reko</option>
<option value="472">Paul</option>
</select>
```

suppose if Alex is selected I need to know that verk, Reko and Paul were left unselected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for taking time to solve my problem but I had found the kinda solution I was looking for. Below is a snap.

```
$('#staff_id').on('change', function() {
    var non_sel_staff = new Array();
    $('#staff_id').find('option').not(':selected').each(function(k,v){
        //console.log(k,v.text, v.value);
        non_sel_staff[k] = v.value; 
    });
console.log(non_sel_staff);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the following:

```
$('#staff_id').on('change', function() {
  var values = $.map($('#staff_id option:not(:selected)'), function(option) {
    return option.value;
  });
});
```

You need to iterate over the jQuery elements to get all the values. When you call `val()`, it calls it on the first element only.

**Demo**

```js
$('#staff_id').on('change', function() {
  var values = $.map($('#staff_id option:not(:selected)'), function(option) {
    return option.value;
  });
  console.log(values)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="mdb-select initialized" id="staff_id" name="staff_id[]" multiple="" searchable="Search here...">
  <option value="0" disabled="" selected="">Select</option>
  <option value="712">Alex</option>
  <option value="468">Verk</option>
  <option value="470">Reko</option>
  <option value="472">Paul</option>
</select>
```

Comment: the solution suggested by you seems fine to work when it come to working with normal select but I am using mdb library it's not giving required results.

Answer (score 1):

You wanted the values and the non-selected?

You can use .map with side effect

```js
$(function() {
  $("#staff_id").on("change",function() {
    var nonSel = [], vals = $("option",this).map(function() {
      if (!this.selected) nonSel.push(this.value)
      else return this.value
    }).get();
    console.log(nonSel,vals)
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="mdb-select initialized" id="staff_id" name="staff_id[]" multiple="" searchable="Search here...">
<option value="0" disabled="" selected="">Select</option>
<option value="712">Alex</option>
<option value="468">Verk</option>
<option value="470">Reko</option>
<option value="472">Paul</option>
</select>
```

Or just loop

```js
$(function() {
  $("#staff_id").on("change",function() {
    var vals = [], nonSel = [];
    $("option",this).each(function() {
      if (this.selected) vals.push(this.value)
      else nonSel.push(this.value)
    });
    console.log(nonSel,vals)
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="mdb-select initialized" id="staff_id" name="staff_id[]" multiple="" searchable="Search here...">
<option value="0" disabled="" selected="">Select</option>
<option value="712">Alex</option>
<option value="468">Verk</option>
<option value="470">Reko</option>
<option value="472">Paul</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd put it in a on change event and then loop through each when the select changes

See fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/vu23oLn1/

```js
$('#staff_id').on('change', function() {
  $('#staff_id option:not(:selected)').each( function(){
  console.log($(this).val());
  }); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="mdb-select initialized" id="staff_id" name="staff_id[]" multiple="" searchable="Search here...">
<option value="0" disabled="" selected="">Select</option>
<option value="712">Alex</option>
<option value="468">Verk</option>
<option value="470">Reko</option>
<option value="472">Paul</option>
</select>
```

Comment: A stacksnippet is more useful in these cases. Your code will take any option on the page btw

Comment: I find a lot of glitches using stackoverflows snippet tool, prefer using fiddle. Updated the code to use specific dropdown. Thanks!

Comment: I use stacksnippet a LOT more than jsfiddle. The console.log is a pain in JSF if not using jQuery. What glitches have you encountered using plain JS and jQuery?